# Run coffeescript method on html input button click

Tags: html, coffeescript, buttonclick

I have the following on my html:

```
<input id="submitbutton" type="submit" />
```

Further down I then have:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
            $('#submitbutton').click() ->
                alert('hello')
</script>
```

Yet when I click the button the alert doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Do you have the CoffeeScript compiler included so that `text/coffeescript` is understood? Anything in the error console? PS: you might want to look at the JavaScript version of your CoffeeScript, it doesn't say what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks, the compiler is included and working elsewhere, but there is an 'uncaught TypeError: object is not a function'

Comment: And have you looked at what `$('#submitbutton').click() -> alert('hello')` gets turned into?

Comment: Looks like it gets turned into $('#submitbutton').click()(function() {
  return alert('hello');
});                                                                  Is there something here that should be obvious? Sorry if so, pretty new to js/coffeescript. I'm not worried about the alert itself, that's just a placeholder for the function to write later, the issue is that I can't get a function to run from the button click

Comment: `f() ->` is the same as `f()(->)` and that's nothing like `f ->`.

Comment: Any idea what the correct coffeescript syntax is? I've tried many things including `$(document).on('click','#submitbutton',->
              alert('hello')
            )`and ` $('#submitbutton').click ->
                alert('hello')`

Comment: `$('#submitbutton').click -> alert('hello')` should work.

Comment: The function is a callback, so it must be passed *to* `.click`. You're calling `click` with no args, then passing your function to `.click()`'s return value. Remove the parens, or wrap 'em around the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to wrap that in another function:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
  $ ->
    $('#submitbutton').click() ->
      alert('hello')
</script>
```

I think (though I am not sure) this is to ensure that the document is fully loaded before that function is bound to the button (so that the button actually exists when the binding takes place)

Based on this question: [How to register Jquery click event with coffeescript on rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669246/how-to-register-jquery-click-event-with-coffeescript-on-rails-3-1)